# How to convert Turkish chars to English chars in a string?

Tags: c#, encoding

string strTurkish = "ÜST";

how to make value of strTurkish as "UST" ?

Comment: Would this be a UTF to ASCII mapping of some kind?

Comment: Will all Turkish characters map to only one character in the range of A-Z a-z?

Comment: is it really be like UST? I guess this is an issue , too. i.e. gitbook.com converts turkish character by adding some new letters. for ÜST they use UEST 
`ö -> oe` `ü->ue` `ı ->ia` `ş->sh` `ç->ch`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
var text = "ÜST";
var unaccentedText  = String.Join("", text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
        .Where(c => char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark));
```

Comment: this won't normalize `ı`. Any other solution?

Comment: `var text = "ÜST";
var unaccentedText  = String.Join("", text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
        .Where(c => char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)).Replace("ı", "i");`
//swh

Answer (score 24):

You can use the following method for solving your problem. The other methods do not convert "Turkish Lowercase I (\u0131)" correctly.

```
public static string RemoveDiacritics(string text)
{
    Encoding srcEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Encoding destEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252); // Latin alphabet

    text = destEncoding.GetString(Encoding.Convert(srcEncoding, destEncoding, srcEncoding.GetBytes(text)));

    string normalizedString = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < normalizedString.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(normalizedString[i]).Equals(UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark))
        {
            result.Append(normalizedString[i]);
        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: For .Net CORE - tested on 3.1+ - you need to add ```Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);``` because ```Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);``` is not supported by default.

Comment: I'ts worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

```
public string TurkishCharacterToEnglish(string text)
{
    char[] turkishChars = {'ı', 'ğ', 'İ', 'Ğ', 'ç', 'Ç', 'ş', 'Ş', 'ö', 'Ö', 'ü', 'Ü'};
    char[] englishChars = {'i', 'g', 'I', 'G', 'c', 'C', 's', 'S', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U'};
    
    // Match chars
    for (int i = 0; i < turkishChars.Length; i++)
        text = text.Replace(turkishChars[i], englishChars[i]);

    return text;
}
```

Comment: easy as that bro. no need to overcomplicate simple things, that's the rule.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not an expert on this sort of thing, but I *think* you can use [`string.Normalize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1.aspx) to do it, by decomposing the value and then effectively removing an non-ASCII characters:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "\u00DCST";
        string normalized = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
        string asciiOnly = new string(normalized.Where(c => c < 128).ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(asciiOnly);
    }    
}
```

It's entirely possible that this does horrible things in some cases though.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem that requires a general solution. It is known that there only 12 special characters in Turkish alphabet that has to be normalized. Those are ı,İ,ö,Ö,ç,Ç,ü,Ü,ğ,Ğ,ş,Ş. You can write 12 rules to replace those with their English counterparts: i,I,o,O,c,C,u,U,g,G,s,S.

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Function Ceng(ByVal _String As String) As String
    Dim Source As String = "ığüşöçĞÜŞİÖÇ"
    Dim Destination As String = "igusocGUSIOC"
    For i As Integer = 0 To Source.Length - 1
        _String = _String.Replace(Source(i), Destination(i))
    Next
    Return _String
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string TurkishChrToEnglishChr(this string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return text;

        Dictionary<char, char> TurkishChToEnglishChDic = new Dictionary<char, char>()
        {
            {'ç','c'},
            {'Ç','C'},
            {'ğ','g'},
            {'Ğ','G'},
            {'ı','i'},
            {'İ','I'},
            {'ş','s'},
            {'Ş','S'},
            {'ö','o'},
            {'Ö','O'},
            {'ü','u'},
            {'Ü','U'}
        };

        return text.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, chr) =>
        {
            if (TurkishChToEnglishChDic.ContainsKey(chr))
                sb.Append(TurkishChToEnglishChDic[chr]);
            else
                sb.Append(chr);

            return sb;
        }).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: There are **six existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted answer with over **twenty votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.