# How can i turn Turkish chars to ascii?

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, ascii

How can I turn Turkish chars to ASCII? (like `ş` to `s`)

I tried replace but it didn't do anything.
Here is my code:

```
$posta = $posta.ToLower()
$posta = $posta -replace "ü","u" 
$posta = $posta -replace "ı","i"
$posta = $posta -replace "ö","o"
$posta = $posta -replace "ç","c"
$posta = $posta -replace "ş","s"
$posta = $posta -replace "ğ","g"
$posta = $posta.trim()
write-host $posta
```

if `$posta` was `eylül` it returns `eylül`

Comment: It works for me. ... and BTW: You can chain `-replace` operators like this: `$posta = $posta -replace 'ü','u' -replace 'ı','i' -replace 'ö','o' -replace 'ç','c' -replace 'ş','s' -replace 'ğ','g'`

Comment: its working now but if i enter öğrenci it returns ogrenci
ogrencI

Comment: So you have an error in your code. You may show it. You can update your question

Comment: code does not return an error

Comment: @DorukHan not returning an error doesn't mean that the code doesn't have any error. It just means there's no syntax error but there are still logical errors in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660761/how-to-convert-turkish-chars-to-english-chars-in-a-string/13660822#13660822) combined with [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660761/how-to-convert-turkish-chars-to-english-chars-in-a-string/13660822#comment72020125_13660822) in the same answer which shows the appropriate way to do it by filtering for characters which are not [`NonSpacingMark`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.unicodecategory?view=net-6.0) followed by replacing `ı` with `i`. The answer is in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) hence sharing how it can be done in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell).

Original answer uses [`Enumerable.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-8.0) which in PowerShell would look like this:

```bash
$posta = 'üıöçşğ'
[string]::new([System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where(
    [char[]] $posta.Normalize([Text.NormalizationForm]::FormD),
    [Func[char, bool]]{ [char]::GetUnicodeCategory($args[0]) -ne [Globalization.UnicodeCategory]::NonSpacingMark })).
    Replace('ı', 'i')
```

However Linq syntax is quite cumbersome in PowerShell as these are not [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) we need to call the APIs directly. A relatively easier approach is to use [`.Where` intrinsic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#foreach-and-where):

```bash
$posta = 'üıöçşğ'
[string]::new($posta.Normalize([Text.NormalizationForm]::FormD).ToCharArray().
    Where{ [char]::GetUnicodeCategory($_) -ne [Globalization.UnicodeCategory]::NonSpacingMark }).
    Replace('ı', 'i')
```

A simplified [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) approach using [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#substituting-in-a-collection), thanks to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) for the tip:

```bash
$posta = 'üıöçşğ'
$posta.Normalize('FormD') -replace '\p{M}' -creplace 'ı', 'i'
```

See [Unicode category or Unicode block: `\p{}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#unicode-category-or-unicode-block-p) for details.

Comment: Nice; you can simplify to: `$posta.Normalize('FormD') -replace '\p{M}' -creplace 'ı', 'i'`

Comment: @mklement0 that's very nice 

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73764185/45375) with a *PowerShell (Core) 7+* alternative, which builds on the guidance in [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16144766/45375), explaining that there is a fixed set of 12 characters in the Turkish alphabet that have equivalent ASCII characters:

- Note: Santiago's answer uses an approach that *generally* removes the accents (diacritics) from letters, and then adds Turkish-specific `ı` handling. The solution below is *specific to the Turkish alphabet* (and is case-sensitive; it could easily be adapted to be case-insensitive / all-lowercase).

```bash
# PS 7+

$turkish = 'ıİöÖçÇüÜğĞşŞ' # Turkish chars. with ASCII equivalents...
$ascii   = 'iIoOcCuUgGsS' # ...and their ASCII equivalents.

# Replace those Turkish chars. that have ASCII equivalents with their equivalents.
# ->  'A_iIoOcCuUgGsS_Z'
'A_ıİöÖçÇüÜğĞşŞ_Z' -replace ('[' + $turkish + ']'),
                            { $ascii[$turkish.IndexOf($_.Value)] }
```

This solution relies on a PowerShell (Core) 7+ feature of the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator, namely the option to pass a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) as the replacement operand, which enables determining the replacement value algorithmically, based on each reported match (`$_.Value`).