# How to substitute accented characters when renaming text files using first line in Powershell

Tags: powershell, file-rename, batch-rename

I'm trying to batch rename plain text files using the first line of each file. I want to keep only alphanumeric characters in with your help I'm almost there. The only issue is that I need accented characters like `é` or `á` to be preserved in a form of their respective not accented characters: e and a (text is in Spanish) or be preserved in the name as they are, not removed. This is what I'm using right now:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {
    $firstLine = ($_ | Get-Content -TotalCount 1) -replace '[^a-z0-9 ]'
    '{0}.txt' -f $firstLine
}
```

Thank you. If possible, please let me know if there is a way to keep the symbol "?" too.

Comment: Since `?` is a wildcard symbol in many shells, one really shouldn't try to use it in a file name. (In MacOS' HFS+ it is a valid character.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to add `á` and `é` to exclusion list of your replacement, ant they will be preserved:

```bash
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {
    ($_ | Get-Content -TotalCount 1 -Encoding UTF8) -replace '[^a-z0-9éá ]', '' -replace '.*', '$0.txt'
}
```

As for `?` - it is not valid symbol for filename in windows, so I don't see a point there. But you always can do multiple replacement, and replace it with something allowed. Like so:

```bash
"asd we'wea?gke é or á? to b" -replace '[^a-z0-9éá ]', '' -replace '\?', '!!!!'
```

Answer (score 3):

Approach is similar to the one used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73764185/15339544), you can use the [`String.Normalize` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=net-8.0) before your regex replacement.

As for not removing `?`, you can simply add it to the character range: `[^a-z0-9 ?]`, however it is an invalid character for file names in Windows, thus not used in the renaming code snippet for this answer. You can use [`[IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars?view=net-7.0) to get the list of invalid characters for your OS.

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {
    $firstLine = ($_ | Get-Content -TotalCount 1 -Encoding utf8).
        Normalize([Text.NormalizationForm]::FormD) -replace '[^a-z0-9 ]'

    '{0}.txt' -f $firstLine
}
```

Example:

```
$string = 'áÁéÉñÑ?'
$string.Normalize([Text.NormalizationForm]::FormD) -replace '[^a-z0-9 ?]'

# Outputs:
# aAeEnN?
```

Worth noting, default [`Get-Content` encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-5.1#-encoding) will be problematic in Windows PowerShell:

> `Default` Uses the encoding that corresponds to the system's active code page (usually ANSI).

Thus the need for `-Encoding utf8`. Newer PowerShell versions don't have such problem as they default to `utf8NoBOM`.

Comment: The fact that all symbols and accented characters get substituted by an "A" may be related to encoding?

Comment: @eera5607 make sure your `.ps1` script is saved using utf8 with BOM encoding. Other than that, will need more details on where you're seeing the issue

Comment: I believe for normalization to work correctly you also need to add `-Encoding UTF8` to `get-content`

Comment: @markalex good point but it has nothing to do with normalization. It has to do with `Get-Content` in PowerShell 5.1 not using the right encoding to read files..

Comment: I mean since it reads something like `Â¿Ã¡` instead of `éá`, it normalized to `AA` and not `ea`. But you totally right, its not normalization's fault.

Answer (score 1):

[Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75892579/45375) shows you how to transform accented letters - such as `é` - to their *unaccented* form, such as `e`, causing them to be covered by the `a-z` regex range expression.

As for **preserving accented characters *as-is*** (which you state is acceptable too):

In lieu of `a-z` you can use **`\p{Ll}`**, which **matches any Unicode lowercase letter** therefore also accented ones (see the [list of all Unicode categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.unicodecategory?view=net-7.0)).
By virtue of `-replace` being case-*insensitive*, *uppercase* letters are implicitly considered as well:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {
  $firstLine = 
    ($_ | Get-Content -TotalCount 1 -Encoding utf8) -replace '[^\p{Ll}0-9 ]'
  '{0}.txt' -f $firstLine
}
```

<sup>Note: I'm using `-Encoding utf8`, as in the other answers, to read your file, which is only necessary in *Windows PowerShell* if your file happens to be UTF-8-encoded but *without a BOM*.</sup>

A simplified example:

```
# -> 'aÄ éE 42'; that is, all letters and digits were preserved.
'a-Ä é/E 42' -replace '[^\p{Ll}0-9 ]'
```

Comment: Thanks, @Santiago. I deliberately left out `?` after reading eera5607's comment in response to vonPryz's comment about how using `?` in _file names_ is best avoided (if even supported, which varies by platform).